# Why do I keep receiving an EOF error for my code?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to solve this problem, but I keep running into the same EOF error and I'm stumped.

Here is the problem:

*Write a program that takes in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse. The program repeats, ending when the user enters "Done", "done", or "d" for the line of text.*

**Essentially if the user types in:**

Hello

Hey

done

**The output should be:**

olleH

yeH

Here is my code:

```
user_inp = input()

while not (user_inp == 'done' or user_inp == 'Done' or user_inp == 'd'):
    
    for i in range(len(user_inp)):
        i += 1
        print(user_inp[-i], end='')
    
    if i == len(user_inp):
        print()
        user_inp = input() #EOF error here
```

If I remove the user_inp = input() at the end of my code, then the code runs the first user_inp endlessly, but that's the line that gives me the EOF error.

Comment: Check your identation of the parts of the loops.

Comment: I don't get an EOF error when I run your code as is. When I run and then enter `hello`, then `world`, then `done`, I get the correct reversed strings printed and then the program exits normally.

Comment: How do you run your code? Do you use some kind of online editor (like paiza.io)?

Comment: I'm taking an online programming class that uses a website called zybooks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is too late for the asker, but for anyone else curious this is how I resolved it. I submitted this to zybooks too.

```
message = input()

while (message != 'done' and message != 'Done' and message != 'd'):
    for i in range(len(message)):
         i += 1
         print(message[-i], end='')

    if i == len(message):
        print()
        message = input()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).